# Reacting to custom key press

Tags: key-bindings, functions

My goal was to improve the php mode. Very often I have to define an array element. And the possible code is this:

```
$array['key']
$array[$key]
```

So, I wanted to create Emacs function, reacting upon clicking '[' key like this:

```
if '[' was clicked once:
    print '[';
if  '[' was clicked twice:
    #this is for the string key
    print "['']";
    move the cursor between "''";
if  '[' was clicked 3 times:
    #this is for the variable as a key
    remove "''" at the center;
    #so we got [<cursor>]
```

I created a function:

```
(defvar *kb--bracket-pressed* 0)
(setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0)

(defun bracket-pressed ()
      "[ key pressed"
      (interactive)
      (cond
            ((= 0 *kb--bracket-pressed*)
                  (insert "[")
                  (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 1)
                  )
            ((= 1 *kb--bracket-pressed*)
                  (insert "'']")
                  (backward-char 2)
                  (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 2)
                  )
            ((= 2 *kb--bracket-pressed*)
                  (delete-char 1)
                  (delete-char -1)
                  (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0)
                  )
            )
      )
```

Then I added a function that will set `*kb--bracket-pressed* = 0` when any non-bracket key was pressed:

```
(defun clean-bracket-pressed ()
      (if (stringp (this-command-keys))
            (when (and
                        (not (= *kb--bracket-pressed* 0))
                        (not (string= (this-command-keys) "["))
                        )
                  (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0))
            )
            (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0)
      )
```

When opening a php file the following hook is launched:

```
(defun my-php-mode ()
  "My php-mode customisations."
      (local-set-key (kbd "[") 'bracket-pressed)
      (add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'clean-bracket-pressed nil 'make-it-local)
)

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-mode)
```

For some reason `clean-bracket-pressed` doesn't work correctly. When I click '[' twice, and then click any other key `*kb--bracket-pressed*` is still equal to 2. While I am expecting it to become 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses are off in the `clean-bracket-pressed` function, and the final `setq` is outside the `if`.  If you reindent using standard Elisp style, this pops right out at you:

```
(defun clean-bracket-pressed ()
  (if (stringp (this-command-keys))
      (when (and
             (not (= *kb--bracket-pressed* 0))
             (not (string= (this-command-keys) "[")))
        (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0)))
  (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0))
```

Your original indentation suggests you want this instead:

```
(defun clean-bracket-pressed ()
  (if (stringp (this-command-keys))
      (when (and
             (not (= *kb--bracket-pressed* 0))
             (not (string= (this-command-keys) "[")))
        (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0))
    (setq *kb--bracket-pressed* 0)))
```

And indeed, after this change everything works as intended.

Comment: No, sorry, it's still equal to 2. Can you try to reproduce on your machine?

Comment: On my machine, I see `*kb--bracket-pressed*` as equal to 1 immediately after a bracket and 0 otherwise (when inspecting in `post-command-hook`).  Maybe the code in your question is different in some way from what's running on your machine?

Comment: Also, I should clarify that the code in my original answer didn't fix the problem, just showed you the problem.  I've edited it to be more explicit.